# Nested query in where

Tags: sql

I have a product table with 6 tuples

```
select productprice
from product
```

gives 6 tuples

```
100.00
70.00
15.00
90.00
150.00
250.00
```

I have a query:

```
SELECT productprice     
FROM    product 
WHERE productprice < (SELECT    
AVG(productprice)FROM product);
```

the result is:

```
100.00
70.00
15.00
90.00
```

If I do

```
SELECT  productprice        
FROM    product 
WHERE (SELECT avg(productprice)
FROM product) > 100
```

then I get:

```
100.00
70.00
15.00
90.00
150.00
250.00
```

Why is it so? Why in the last query the condition is overlooked? It still returns ALL the tuples irrespective of the condition.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is not overlooked, it's just not related to the main query.
The subquery `(SELECT AVG(c)FROM table 1)` returns a scalar value, that is not effected in any way by the outer query.

In the first two examples, you've compared that scalar value to a column of the table in the outer query, that's why it effected the results.

In the last query, you've compared it to a constant value - so if the average value of the `c` column is larger than 2 (which is the constant value you've used), the outer query will return all the rows of the table. If you would change the `>` to `<` in the last query, it will return no rows at all.

**Update**

Based on the data you've updated on the question, the average value of `productprice` for the entire table is `112.5`.

In the second query, you are returning all th rows where the `productprice` value is less than `112.5`.

As for the third query - your `where` condition is  `112.5 > 100` - and therefor the `select` statement returns all the rows in the table.

Comment: Thanks! . I have edited my post with real data. It still unclear to me. It seems that there is no effect of the condition.

Comment: oh.. i  got it.. the condition 112.5 > 100 is true. Its not that average price is compared. Thanks!

Comment: The average price is compared, it's just that the average price is computed for the entire table and then compared to a hard-coded value. If it was compared to a column in the outer query, than it could effect the amount of rows returned. Since it's compared to a constant, it really is an all-or-nothing condition.

Answer (score 0):

The selection in your final query has nothing to do with the content of your rows.

In the preceding queries, you are comparing the value of c on that row with the average, which will differ on a row-by-row basis.

In the last query, you are selecting where the average of all the rows c values is greater than 100. You will either get all rows or none, depending on whether the average is greater than 100 or not. In this case, the average is 112.5 so your where clause is effectively `WHERE 112.5 > 100` which is true for all rows.

To get a subset of the row data, you need to select on some criteria that differs on the rows. For example, `WHERE c > 100` would return just two rows (150 and 250).

Comment: Thanks!  I was also expecting the same thing but the result is a little weird.  I edited my post with a real example.

Comment: Yes, the average of all rows is 112.5 so your last query is "show me any rows where 112.5 > 100" which holds true for all rows, so you get all rows. You have nothing in your WHERE clause that selects based on the data in the individual rows so you will get everything or nothing. Reverse the > into < and you will get no rows. To get a subset of data your selection criteria need to be based on the data in each row, not dataset-wide aggregations like average.